# Score does not persist while navigating within app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have placed a code to keep score on a page within an app. The code functions properly within the page, however, when you navigate to other pages within the app, and return to increase the score, it has automatically reset to zero. I would like it to retain the score throughout the duration of time spent on the app. If they exit the app, then it is okay to reset to zero, but while they are navigating within the pages of the app I would like the player to have the ability to increase scores and keep track of who is winning the game. Please advise me as to what I can do to allow the score to persist. Thank you!

Here is the functional part of the code:

```
`enter code here`<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    const PLAYERS = [
        { name: "Player 1", score: 0, id: 1 },
        { name: "Player 2", score: 0, id: 2 },
        { name: "Player 3", score: 0, id: 3 },
        { name: "Player 4", score: 0, id: 4 },
        { name: "Player 5", score: 0, id: 5 },
    ];

    var nextId = 6;

    class AddPlayerForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                name: "",
            };
        }

        onNameChange(e) {
            this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
        }

        onSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            this.props.onAdd(this.state.name);
            this.setState({ name: "" });
        }

        render() {
            return React.createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "add-player-form" },
                React.createElement(
                    "form",
                    { onSubmit: (e) => this.onSubmit(e) },
                    React.createElement(
                        "input",
                        { type: "text", value: this.state.name, onChange: (e) => this.onNameChange(e) },
                        null
                    ),
                    React.createElement(
                        "input",
                        { type: "submit", value: "Add Player" },
                        null
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }

    AddPlayerForm.propTypes = {
        onAdd: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }


    function Header(props) {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            { className: "header" },
            React.createElement(
                "h1",
                null,
                props.title
            )
        );
    }

    Header.propTypes = {
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        players: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    };

    function Counter(props) {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            { className: "counter" },
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "counter-score" },
                props.score
            ),
            React.createElement(
                "button",
                { className: "counter-action increment", onClick: () => props.onChange(1) },
                "+"
            )
        );
    }

    Counter.propTypes = {
        score: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }

    function Player(props) {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            { className: "player" },
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "remove-player" },
                React.createElement(
                    "a",
                    { onClick: (e) => props.onRemove(e) },
                    "✖"
                )
            ),
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "player-name" },
                props.name
            ),
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "player-score" },
                React.createElement(
                    Counter,
                    { score: props.score, onChange: (e) => props.onScoreChange(e) },
                    null
                )
            )
        );
    }

    Player.propTypes = {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        score: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        onScoreChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        onRemove: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    class Application extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                players: props.initialPlayers,
            };
        }

        onScoreChange(index, delta) {
            let players = [...this.state.players]
            players[index].score += delta;
            players = players.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)
            this.setState({ players });
        }

        onPlayerAdd(name) {
            this.state.players.push({
                name: name,
                score: 0,
                id: nextId,
            });
            this.setState(this.state);
            nextId += 1;
        }

        onRemovePlayer(index) {
            this.state.players.splice(index, 1);
            this.setState(this.state);
        }

        // reorderPlayers

        render() {
            return React.createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "scoreboard" },
                React.createElement(
                    Header,
                    { title: this.props.title, players: this.state.players },
                    null
                ),
                React.createElement(
                    "div",
                    { className: "players" },
                    ...this.state.players.map((player, index) =>
                        React.createElement(
                            Player,
                            {
                                onScoreChange: (delta) => this.onScoreChange(index, delta),
                                onRemove: () => this.onRemovePlayer(index),
                                name: player.name,
                                score: player.score,
                                key: player.id
                            },
                            null
                        )
                    )
                ),
                React.createElement(
                    AddPlayerForm,
                    { onAdd: (name) => this.onPlayerAdd(name) },
                    null
                )
            );
        }
    }

    Application.defaultProps = {
        title: "Scoreboard"
    };
    Application.propTypes = {
        title: PropTypes.string,
        initialPlayers: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
            name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            score: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        })).isRequired,
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(
            Application,
            { initialPlayers: PLAYERS },
            null
        ),
        document.getElementById('container')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with navigation? I'm not seeing any router specific code.

Comment: Maybe I used the word "navigate" improperly. Within the app are multiple pages, one of which is the code page containing the scoreboard. You are able to increase the score incrementally within the code page but when you switch to other pages of the app and come back into the scoreboard it has reset to zero. I would like the score to remain.

Comment: I think you should have a look at [React router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) or any other Router for React. If you're navigating away from your app by opening a new html page, you'll reset everything (same behaviour as reloading the page). Reloading could be fixed by using [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the state of your app but for navigating I would use a router.